# Position Menu component using material UI react storybook

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm working on Menu component using material ui , where i need to map menu to storybook. I want user can change the position of menu component as per their need. Can i map **anchorOrigin** & **transformOrigin** dynamically. As i'm new to React, not sure how to achieve it. Thanks . Below is my code.

```
export const Menu= ({ }) => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    };
    const handleClose = () => {
        setAnchorEl(null);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
                <Button
                    id="demo-positioned-button"
                    aria-controls={open ? 'demo-positioned-menu' : undefined}
                    aria-haspopup="true"
                    aria-expanded={open ? 'true' : undefined}
                    onClick={handleClick}
                    style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}
                >
                    Dashboard
                </Button>
            </ThemeProvider>
            <Menu
                id="demo-positioned-menu"
                aria-labelledby="demo-positioned-button"
                anchorEl={anchorEl}
                open={open}
                onClose={handleClose}
                anchorOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'left',
                }}
                transformOrigin={{
                    vertical: 'top',
                    horizontal: 'left',
                }}
            >
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    );
}

**stories.js**

export const position= Menu.bind({});
```